# Some cyrillic symbols are read incorrectly by Google App Engine's URLConnection

Tags: java, google-app-engine, unicode, character-encoding

I'm using simple code to retrieve a JSON object. The JSON is in Unicode and contains some Cyrillic characters.

```
URL url = new URL("blahblah");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new inputStreamReader(con
    .getInputStream()));
String json = reader.readLine();
```

The code works perfectly fine in "standard" Java implementation:

> Владивосток

However, when I use the same snippet in a Google App Engine application, some Cyrillic letters become replaced with �? characters:

> �?ладиво�?�?ок

I've noticed that, from the [basic Cyrillic character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode#Basic_Cyrillic_alphabet), only the middle half (symbols with codes 0421-043F) is read correctly. I don't know what to make of it though.

Is this behavior caused by Google's reimplementation of `java.net` classes, or is it my oversight somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the same encoding that was used to create and send the data on the other server/source.

Specify the same encoding in the constructor of [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

For example if you want to use UTF-8 encoding:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    con.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

If you don't explicitly specify the encoding, quoting from the [javadoc of the constructor that doesn't take the encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader-java.io.InputStream-):

> Creates an `InputStreamReader` that uses the **default** charset.

So the platform dependent default charset will be used, so it might work differently on different operating systems. So always specify the charset.

**Edit:**

It is advised to use the encoding reported by the server. You can get this by [`URLConnection.getContentEncoding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentEncoding--):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    con.getInputStream(), con.getContentEncoding()));
```

Comment: I've tried to explicitly set the encoding to StandardCharsets.UTF_8, but with an opposite effect of turning all symbols to question marks. Turns out, the JSON was created with another obscure encoding, although getContentType() was returning "charset=utf8". I've specified the correct charset, and everything works good now. Thank you for the help!